# Set value on GameObject.transform.position[index] with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a float array to store GameObject.position value, how can I give the value to the GameObject.position by using indexing?

```
var positions = new [0f,10f,12f];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
GameObject.position[i] = positions[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Transform.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) is a [**property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) with a getter and a setter.

You can not directly assign individual components - since it *would* basically only apply it to the returned `Vector3` from the getter but not invoke the setter.

You always need to get and set an entire `Vector3` value to the property like

```
var vector = Vector3.zero;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    vector[i] = positions[i]
}
GameObject.transform.position = vector;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Transform. Transform has position, rotation and scale. To set position you can set only full value, so:

```
GameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(positions[0], positions[1], positions[2]);
```